# Вывод элементов массива

Tags: php

```
while($m = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo $m;
}
```

Этот цикл извлекает из массива по одному значению и присваевает его переменной `$m`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну почти, только он извлекает массив значений и $m содержит в себе массив, соответствующий одной строке из выполненного запроса. При следующей итерации массива, в нем следующая строка и т.д.